# How make alert dialog pointing from a button on click of button?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm having a requirement where i need to display some as below.

[image: AlertDialog]

But i'm as shown below.

[image: CurrentDialog]

The code that i'm using to get the above dialog is as below.

```
ListView visitsListView = (ListView) vg.findViewById(R.id.lvDayRemindersList);
        //if ( visitsListView == null ) return;
        TextView noVisitDayTextView = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.no_visits_day);
        if ( visitsListView == null && day != null )
        {
            //activityListDialog = new AlertDialog(vg.getContext());
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) vg.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = li.inflate(R.layout.cal_month_day_list_view, null, false);
            visitsListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.today_list_view);
            //noVisitDayTextView = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.today_list_view_title);
            //activityListDialog.setContentView(v);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(vg.getContext());
            builder.setTitle(day);
            builder.setView(v);
            activityListDialog = builder.create();
            activityListDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        }
```

On click of the grid i'm calling the dialog as shown below.

```
if (isContainsData && isOnSelected) 
        {
            Logger.performanceLogEnd("CalendarMonthView-displayVisitListDialog");
            activityListDialog.show();
        }
```

Could someone please help in achieving this. Thank you.

Comment: check popupwindow http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rajen, i have gone through the link before. But not able to find which function to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I notice is that there is no code for filling up the content of object `visitsListView`. At least I don't see the code. `visitsListView` is being used twice from calling `findViewById`(), and that is confusing.

Perhaps it is good if you post the xml layout cal_month_day_list_view and others.